# Does anyone knows what this font is? or similar font?

Tags: font-identification

I searched the font sites but failed to find similar.

[image: Rounded Cartoon Font]

Comment: this is the font from photoshop with applied stroke effects and distortions

Comment: This looks more like lettering (=custom designed letterforms) than an actual typeface.

Comment: @Bakabaka look at the whole picture - definitely it is a font with effects - http://images.michaels.com/dw/staging/michaels-catalog/canada-feature/kd4271_CN.jpg

Comment: I stand corrected :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the font you're looking for is [casual](http://www.whatfontis.com/Casual.font?text=Washable%20Kids%27%20Paint)

[image: Casual]

Answer (score 3):

i think this one is very similar

[image]

Sweet as candy by Pizzadude